# keep image in place relative to screen size CSS div id

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set my position statically to the right side of the screen as thats where the logo I am trying to keep is. On different monitors it will flow of the screen.... Is there a way to set this statically, this is what I have right now for my slide... (using a parallax theme so I cannot force the position throughout the page, just the slide.)

```
<div id="slide-6996" class="slide slide-6996 cycle-slide-active slide-left light" style="background-image:url(http://18.205.33.160/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/ITData_HomePage2018_01.jpg);">
  <div class="slide-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="slide-caption">
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h1><strong>COMPREHENSIVE IT SERVICES YOU CAN TRUST</strong></h1>
        </div>
        <h2 class="slide-title">Let us help you develop an IT Optimization Strategy and Define your technological priorities</h2>
        <a class="slide-link button button-medium" href="http://18.205.33.160/index.php/itone-method/?customize_changeset_uuid=a588c51b-d8d4-4089-90c1-df8e14656af2&amp;customize_autosaved=on&amp;customize_messenger_channel=preview-2" target="_self">Learn how we can help you succeed</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide-image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried in CSS so far along with fixed positions (broke the page)

```
#slide-6996 {
width: 100%;}
```

Is there a way to keep the width at 100% and lock the image to the right of the slide and still be able to scroll past using CSS?

Comment: for a certain position you can check the position attribute https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp, as when it comes to the screen size probably media queries would help

Comment: @mdln97 position fixed or relative dont work for me with right: 0; for my situation, I will look into media queries and post if i find the answer

Comment: media queries don't appear to do what I need on first glance, is there something specific you had in mind?

Comment: I had not seen the link you had in the post from the first time, I had something else in my mind

Comment: @mdln97 no problem I appreciate you trying to help regardless, I am also willing to use a combination of html and css if that helps :)

Comment: If you use `vw` as your size unit instead of `%` you can achieve this effect purely with CSS, have a look into that.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but that is not a user friendly link, and something I wouldn't click on just to help someone out. I know you're new, so you should look into something stackoverflow offers, [runnable snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so people can view your code while reading your question, without needing to go to any other links. (This is not true for mobile apps though) but its much more user friendly than a TLD using only the IP address.

Comment: Sorry, Still kind of a noob, however I have no bad intentions, will edit out the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the logo shown in the main image that is added as a background image then all you need to do is add the following:

```
#slide-6996 {
    background-position: right;
}
```

This will keep the background aligned to the right so that the logo remains on the page however it will eventually slide under your text at smaller layouts. Perhaps you should use a media query to switch the alignment back to left at that point.

Another unfortunate side effect is due to the fact you have a whitebar on that side of your image you are going to be stuck with that unless you use an image without that. To save you the trouble ive edited it out myself and uploaded the image here: https://ibb.co/12dNQdn

Comment: You are a saint sir, I am not at my computer at the moment, but I appreciate the help very much, will give it a shot momentarily

Comment: worked perfectly for me, thank you again, spent a lot of time trying to figure this one out!

Comment: @jblaupunkt No worries. Glad I could help